# Type of regression

Tags: r, regression, terminology

I have a regression model that looks like this:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_1 X_2 + \beta_4 X_1X_2$$

What is the correct name for this regression: multiple linear regression? polynomial regression? or something else?

Comment: Regular old linear regression.

Comment: `b_3*X_1*X_2 + b_4*X_1*X_2` seems redundant, is that a typo?

Comment: Maybe to add '…with interactions'.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's a typo. I just want to show that there are interactions in the equation.

Comment: Aside from "interaction", you can also call `b_3*X_1*X_2` a feature cross

Answer (score 3):

That is a multiple linear regression with two interaction terms, probalbly with a typo, because there is unnecessary redundancy of the b_3 and the b_4 term which seem to be identical. Thus the model is probably underidentified, unless you use special regression techniques (regularized like Bayesian with non-flat priors or ridge regression etc could probably compute that, though I cannot imagine a situation where that would be useful).

If this was to be put in R formula type you could denote it as

`y ~ X_1 * X_2`

because in the formula notation, the `*` implies the single terms and the intercept `b` automatically.